# QML crashes when changing Text.text

Tags: qml

I am new to QML and so I tried a couple of things. Most works, but the Programm always crashes, when I try to change the `text`-element.

E.g.:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Text {
        id: mytex
        // text: area.mouseX + " / " + area.mouseY
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: area
        anchors.fill: parent
        // hoverEnabled: true
        // onClicked: { mytex.text = mouseX + " / " + mouseY }
        onMouseXChanged: { mytex.text = mouseX + " / " + mouseY }
    }
}
```

All I want is a text, that shows the current mouse coordinates (whenever I click or better, whenever I hover the `MouseArea` )

I use QtQuick 2.3 with mingw on a Windows-Machine.

---

Edit:
I tried the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    property int count: 0
    property string countstr: count.toString()

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            count += 1
            console.log(countstr)
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr(countstr + ' times clicked')
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

with the QTcreator on both my Windows and my Linux machine.
On Linux it runs flawless.
Therefore I conclude, it *should* work (and can finally stop the frustrating search for a fault in my code)  but I still don't know why it does not work on Windows.

In debugging mode it sais (for the latter code):

```
qrc:/main.qml:20:5: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "text"
qrc:/main.qml:20:5: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "text"
qrc:/main.qml:20:5: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "text"
qrc:/main.qml:20:5: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "text"
QQmlExpression: Expression qrc:/main.qml:21:15 depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:
```

...

Comment: Try a newer Qt version. Also, please paste a stack trace.

Comment: It does not change when changing to a version 5.6.
I don't know how to retrieve the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `mouseX` and `mouseY` don't get updated even if hover is enabled. A short test in qmlscene worked for the code you find on the bottom. Hope it helps.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Text {
        id: mytex
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: area
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onPositionChanged: {
            mytex.text = mouseX + " / " + mouseY
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple and easy: My graphic card was running in compatibility mode. Installing the appropriate propriatery driver solved this problem.

Therfore the OpenGL-Engine crashed. -.-'